# Adding `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` as VM argument stops the server

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmx, spring-jmx

So I have been facing issue when I add `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` to my server vm arguments, it just stops. Is there something obvious that I am missing ? FYI - This is a spring boot application.

Here's how I am starting the server

```
java \
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1199 \
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
> -XX:+FlightRecorder \
> -server -jar my-app.jar
```

`-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` and `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099` both give the problem. If I remove them, server starts.

Comment: What kind of server? are you just running the embedded tomcat using `java -jar`?

Comment: Yes embedded jetty.

Comment: You can't use the same port for jmx and rmi.

Comment: they are different

Comment: Perhaps stupid question, but there are not any spaces after the line continuation characters?

Comment: does the problem go away if you remove `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \` and leave the rest?

Comment: `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` and `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099` both give the problem. If I remove them, server starts.

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: It is a Java 11, I have also tried Java 8 earlier